# all the tables where rows are not null from database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL server 2008,I want all the tables whose row count is not NULL
Can somebody help out?

Comment: It is impossible for a row count to be `NULL`. Do you mean you want all tables with > 0 rows?

Comment: yes..I want all the tables have atleast one row entry

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way (includes effects of uncommitted transactions)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id), SUM(rows)
FROM sys.partitions p 
WHERE index_id < 2 and OBJECTPROPERTYEX (object_id ,'IsUserTable' ) = 1
GROUP BY p.object_id
HAVING SUM(rows) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Very quick and dirty way:

In SSMS, right-click on database, Select Reports-> Standard Reports -> Disk Usuage by Top Tables

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use the undocumented procedure `sp_MSForEachTable`

```
Create Table ##TempRowCount
(
TableName nvarchar(max),
NumberOfRows int
)
Exec sp_msforeachTable 'Insert Into ##TempRowCount select ''?'', count(*) From ?'

Select * From ##TempRowcount
Where NumberOfRows > 0

Drop Table ##TempRowCount
```

This may take some time to run depending on the size of your database and tables.

Comment: @Mitch - I have edited that in to my answer, I forgot to mention it in my original answer. Thanks